# Probability of a car passing without colliding with pillars?

Tags: probability

On a road 10m wide there are 2 pillars each 2m wide. What is the probability an 1m wide car will pass the road? Do the position of pillars matter?

I was playing Trackmania, kept colliding with the pillars so tried to figure out the probability but just dividing `free area/ total area` seems wrong. Best I could think is `free area (only considering segments equal or wider than the car)/ total area`